# C++ Long integer display

Tags: c++, long-integer, display

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map> 
using namespace std;

map<pair<int, int>, int> d;

auto trav(int m, int n) {

    if (d.find(make_pair(m, n)) != d.end()) return d[make_pair(m, n)];

    if (m == 0 || n == 0) return 0;
    if (m == 1 && n == 1) return 1;

    d[make_pair(m, n)] = trav(m - 1, n) + trav(m, n - 1);

    return d[make_pair(m, n)];
}

int main() {

    cout << trav(3, 3) << endl;
    cout << long int(trav(18, 18)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to C++, I have display issue when displaying the second base case trav(18,18) a negative number is displayed instead of a positive long integer positive number that is expected

Comment: everything is done with `int`s in your code. You only cast to `long int` after the overflow already occured

Comment: i tried storing the passing values in long int variable but that did not make a difference as well

Comment: change your map to `map<pair< int, int>, long int> d;` and also corresponding return type to `long int trav(...)`

Comment: tried it does not make any difference

Comment: What problem you get ? It seems to work https://godbolt.org/z/eKx44Y. I get o/p as 2333606220 and not a negative number

Comment: these are the outputs I get, I am in visual studio 6,
-1961361076

Comment: Never assume you have only one bug. You may correct one bug and still get the wrong answer because of a subsequent error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast here is too late:

```
cout << long int(trav(18, 18)) << endl;
```

As everything in `trav` is calculated with `int`s the possible overlflow happens before the cast. Once the overflow happened casting afterwards is of no use. I do get correct looking results when I change the calculations to use `long int`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map> 
using namespace std;

map<pair<long int,long int>, long int> d;

auto trav(long int m,long  int n) {

    if (d.find(make_pair(m, n)) != d.end()) return d[make_pair(m, n)];

    if (m == 0 || n == 0) return 0L;
    if (m == 1 && n == 1) return 1L;

    d[make_pair(m, n)] = trav(m - 1, n) + trav(m, n - 1);

    return d[make_pair(m, n)];
}

int main() {

    cout << trav(3, 3) << endl;
    cout << trav(18, 18) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Output:](https://godbolt.org/z/c77TfY)

```
6
2333606220
```